# Fastest way to load data into buffer object?

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I am loading static data from CPU memory to an OpenGL buffer object.
The data needs to be reformatted (i.e. filtered).

Which of the following is fastest:

1) Copy and filter the data on the CPU. Then call glBufferData once.

2) Filter the data as it's uploaded to the GPU by multiple calls to glBufferSubData

3) Filter the data as it's uploaded to the GPU using a mapped buffer with glMapBuffer

Comment: Several times it was `glBufferData`, that was fastest for me, but other people, said `glMapBuffer`, was fastest on their machines. No way to know for sure.

Comment: can you clarify? did you say 1) was fastest for you? several times?

Comment: Yes, but other people claim the opposite and how could it be different? OpenGL implementations span multiple architectures and OSes. There are bound to be difference in what works best between them.

Answer (score 1):

All three of these approaches end up filtering the data on the CPU and then queuing commands for the GPU to copy over the data to the video card.  The GPU operations are largely going to be dependent on the OpenGL implementation, but it seems like your best bet for achieving the minimum time for the total set of operations (filtering and copying) is to try to get as much concurrency as possible.

To me, this would imply that your best approach is to create a worker thread acting as a producer, and make the primary thread (the one that can talk to OpenGL) a consumer, so that filtering and copying can happen concurrently.  This would necessarily mean you'd have to use approach 2 or 3, because approach one would simply serialize the operations.

So, write a thread which iterates over the data to be filtered and pushes the post-processed data into a shared queue.  On the main thread, create a loop which takes data currently in the queue and copies it to OpenGL.  You need a signal mechanism to tell the primary thread when all data has been pushed into the buffer, so that it knows at that point that if the buffer is empty it can exit the loop.

Comment: That's a good advice, but it answers a different question.
Here, I am trying to compare those three API calls (in single threaded case, or compare 2) and 3) in the multi threaded if you want). Any pointers on that?
For example if I stick to single thread and 1) and 2) are equivalent, then 2) is obviously better, since it doesn't do an extra copy.

Comment: With the multi-threaded approach you describe, I think you could avoid the extra shared queue if you use `glMapBuffer`. If the main thread maps the buffer, it would be fine for a secondary thread to write into the mapped buffer memory. Of course you still need thread synchronization so that the main thread knows when all the data has been written, so that it can unmap the buffer, and start to use it for rendering.